# Remove [[ ]] from multi ArrayList (toString Method)?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, collections

I realize toString method adds the [], and in this case multiple brackets i.e. `[[ value ]].`

**I need to remove the brackets, and convert into string format, like this output...**

```
a  b  c
e  f  g
i  h  j
```

Current output...

```
[[a], [b], [c]]
[[d], [e], [f]]
[[i], [h], [g]]
```

**Attempt:**  I have an iterable method but not sure if that's needed to be used for this purpose?

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>> matrixOne;

public String toString() {
    return matrixOne.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","");
}
```

**update HERE IS A WORKING VERIFIABLE CODE. Gets this output:**

```
public class Matrix<T> implements Iterable {

    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private int value;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>> matrixOne;


public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

         matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>();
//       matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
                matrixOne.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>());

                for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) { 
                matrixOne.get(i).add(new ArrayList<T>()); 
                }
            } 

    }   

public void insert(int row, int column, T value) {
    matrixOne.get(row).get(column).add( value);
}

 // THIS METHOD!
public String toString() {

    return matrixOne.toString().replaceAll("\[\[|\]|,|\[|\]\]", "");
}

public Iterator iterator() {
      Iterator itr = matrixOne.iterator();
      return itr;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix<String> nums = new Matrix(3, 3);
        nums.insert(0, 0, "a");
        nums.insert(0, 1, "b");
        nums.insert(0, 2, "c");
//
        nums.insert(1, 0, "d");
        nums.insert(1, 1, "e");
        nums.insert(1, 2, "f");
//
        nums.insert(2, 2, "g");
        nums.insert(2, 1, "h");
        nums.insert(2, 0, "i");

        for(Object nm : nums) {
            System.out.println(nm.toString());
        }
```

Ideas please?

Comment: you need to use replaceAll() or else it will only replace the first matching char

Comment: Why don't you just print the string using loop.

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Your output looks like you are not even executing your custom method. Show how you create the data and print it.  A simple replace(...) works for me.

Comment: @StephenC OP is using [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), so not regex.

Comment: @Austin [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) will replace all instances: *Replaces **each** substring ...*

Comment: @Austin  `you need to use replaceAll() or else it will only replace the first matching char` - replace(...) works for me.

Comment: (1-) Still waiting for a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Your update does nothing. It just displays the default toString() of the Object. Nowhere do you have the code to do the replace(...).

Comment: `update HERE IS A WORKING VERIFIABLE CODE.` - still doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace(...) works for me:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al1.add("a");
        al1.add("b");
        ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al2.add("1");
        al2.add("2");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        al.add(al1);
        al.add(al2);

        System.out.println(al);
        System.out.println( al.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "") );
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta love all the down votes. Did the down voter even try the code? Please explan what the problem is. It seems like a simple solution to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure who is down voting everyone, but i tried you answer, it hasn't worked. I've updated the question so as to show how i've instantiated this List:    matrixOne = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>();
 (which is different to yours), please take a look? @camickr

Comment: @Shaz, did you copy my code and execute it? Are the "[" and "]} removed? The point of my answer is to demonstrate that the String.replace(...) method works. So if your toString(...) method on the object has "[" and "]" in the String, then the code I provided will remove them. `I've updated the question` - I can't copy/paste/compile and text your code. I don't know what a "Matrix" is. That is not part of JDK8. I don't even see where you do the replace. Post a proper [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: I've updated with a workiing example, just run it on eclipse

Comment: tried returning this in the toString method:   return matrixOne.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

Comment: @Shaz `I've updated with a workiing example,` - doesn't even compile. You don't implement "Iterable". You don't even need iterable. You just need to display the "nums" variable since that is your Matrix with implements the toString() method.

Comment: `tried returning this in the toString method...` - works fine for me. Again, post the actual code you are testing!!!

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The test case is actually the  code in the public main in the question. I need to implement Iterable with this class and part of the class blueprint, and therefore for the for(Object nm : nums) to work (in public main).... The class has another method, which i've added to the question is this but i'm not sure how I'd use this (remember I need to use the iterable class), maybe i can you this method to iterate the list using your replace all method? :  public Iterator iterator() {
       Iterator itr = matrixOne.iterator();
       return itr;
 }

Comment: @Shaz,  The point of a toString() is to return the representation of the entire object, not just one row of the object. So the only code you need in your main() method is `System.out.println( nums );` And then use the code from my suggestion to replace the unwanted characters. If you want each row of the matrix printed on a different line, then you need to customize the toString() method to do this. If you want to use an Iterator, then it should be part of the toString(), not the main() method.

Comment: Ahh! I see! Right, it works... but if i need it to be on a new line (each row \n) with a tab \t for each  value... how is this implemented in your solution please?

Comment: ideas please? how do i get it to the output example in the question?